# block until reverseGeocode has returned

Tags: ios, objective-c, geocode

I am trying to find a user's location from a coordinate to save into my database.

To find the location name I am using **reverseGeocode**. However since it is a block method my self.locationName will return (and save as nil) into the database. So I have tried to find a solution to the problem, and tried to put together the following solution using semaphores to try and block until I get a locationName I can save, but the app just hangs when the save button is pressed. Should I even be going about this problem in this way or is there a better way?

```
 dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore;

 - (void)reverseGeocode:(CLLocation *)location {
     CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks,                    NSError *error) {

     NSLog(@"Finding address");
     if (error) {
     NSLog(@"Error %@", error.description);
     } else {
     CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
     self.locationName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary(placemark.addressDictionary, NO)];
     dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);         
            }
     }];
     }



-(NSString *)findLocation:(CLLocation *)startingLocation
{
semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
[self reverseGeocode:startingLocation];
 dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); //should maybe timeout
return self.locationName;
}
```

Comment: Rework your code so that instead of `findLocation:` returning a string, have it instead take in a block which you can then call upon your reverse geocode method finishing. That block will handle saving the location name in your database.

Comment: To expand on Gavin's answer, it is almost never the correct approach to make a synchronous network (or other long-running process) call.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Gavin. I knew I was trying to create a workaround when I started thinking semaphores!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are thinking about this all wrong. That is not how asynchronous code works. Do *NOT* block until the code returns. Just launch the code to start the reverse geocode, and finish up. Now when the reverse geocode finishes, it calls you back and you can do whatever you want with the returned info. That is the whole point of the completion handler: it doesn't run until the reverse geocode has completed.

Just get rid of the semaphores and let things happen asynchronously. Here is a complete example without the secondary method:

```
CLLocation* loc = userLocation.location;
[geo reverseGeocodeLocation:loc
          completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
  {
      if (placemarks) {
          CLPlacemark* p = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
          NSLog(@"%@", p.addressDictionary); // do something with address
      }
  }];
```

As you've already been told, if you really want to call this from another method and then do something further, then pass a block to this method and call the block inside the completion handler. That means the block you passed is code that will run when the geocoding has completed, which is exactly what you want - without semaphores and without freezing the app.

Freezing the app is bad form and the WatchDog will kill your app dead if you do it for too long. Just don't do it.

Comment: what does "finish up" "it calls you back" mean??

Comment: "finish up" means stop. Your code ends. Now the interface will not freeze. "It calls you back" means the completion handler at last runs (perhaps some long time after you started the process).

Comment: But how do I know the completion handler runs before I try to save the locationName? This code is also in a separate class from the database class I am calling it from. So i just want to make sure I have the location name and can save it. I don't want to wait 'sometime' for it to happen before I continue.

Comment: You do not wait. That is the whole point. You must structure your architecture so that it doesn't matter when the completion happens. That is what asynchronous is all about.

Comment: It might help you to look at this example of mine: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch24p842downloader/ch37p1099downloader/MyDownloader.m We pass in a completion handler when we call `download:completionHander:`. The completion handler is stored. Later - maybe a long time later! - `URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:` is called; at that point we whip out the completion handler we were given at the outset, and call it! Thus, we _call back_ to the client who originally called `download:completionHander:`, in good order, when the time comes.